# Webmin and command line cannot read Apache2 logs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

My apache2 directory for logs is under /var/log/apache2 and I cannot cd into it as I get permission denied. Even if I use `sudo su` and cd into it and nano a log file it is just blank but I know its not because of the file size.

The /var/apache2 dir is part of root:adm and it never use to be adm I'm pretty sure?

Also on Webmin when I try and view the logs inside /var/log/apache2 in the Webmin editor the logs show up for like a second and then just shows a blank text area?

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with `sudo usermod -a -G adm <username>`